# Woocommerce conditional field depending gateway choice

Tags: woocommerce, gateway

It's possible to create a custom field that depends on the gateway choice?
For example, if I choose BACS a field named ONE will show, while if I choose another gateway ONE field disappears and a field named TWO appears...